# Lost Users & Groups

Tags: virtual-machine, docker, root, kvm, shared-folders

What is happened, if the groups and users were lost in a folder like this ...

```
Result of ls-lsa

4 drwxr-xr-x 6 64055 64055 4096 Jan 12 20:57 .
4 drwxr-xr-x 3 64055 64055 4096 Jan 11 13:25 ..
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 64055 64055  837 Jan 12 20:56 docker-compose.yml
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 64055 64055 4096 Jan 12 20:52 plugins
0 -rw-r--r-- 1 64055 64055    0 Jan 12 20:57 test
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 64055 64055 4096 Jan 12 20:52 themes
4 drwxr-xr-x 2 64055 64055 4096 Jan 12 20:52 uploads
4 drwxr-xr-x 5 64055 64055 4096 Jan 13 10:53 .wordpress
4 -rw-r--r-- 1 64055 64055  837 Jan 12 20:55 wordpress.yml
```

The whole thing happened in a KVM virtual machine, while docker-compose created a container in a shared directory (Shared Folder host_files above) with the host. I was logged on as root. Before the container creation, the parent folder had the user and group root.

Does anyone have an explanation for this error, please? Questions are welcome!

Thx a lot ...

Answer (score 0):

The uid/gid 64055 is [reserved for libvirt-qemu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=843881#10), the owner of the KVM subsystem. Also see [libvirt: use allocated uid/gid for libvirt-qemu](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=844339) for the reasoning behind having a fixed uid/gid. (Arguably it should have been a low-valued system uid, but it isn't.)

As to the change in ownership from 0/0 to 64055/64055, I can't explain that. Maybe it's a consequence of interaction between Docker and KVM.

Comment: The uid / gid matches with the previous user / group. That calms me down a bit for now.

I thank you for your help. Your contribution brought some clarity to my problem.

I have since decided to change the location of the container.